# Reading and writing dates to the registry for trial version purposes

Tags: c#, registry

Here's what I want to do, I want to store the date the first time the program is installed and also store a date when was the program was last run. I want the code to check to see if it was more than 30 days since the installation so I can turn off features. I also want to check if the system date is less than the last opened date and if so write the installed date to 1/1/1901 to prevent the program from running.

Keeping in mind that this is not a consumer program but a business program I don't expect hackers to crack it, they may do but that is fine I simply want to give potential customers a reason to consider purchasing the program and the end of the trial will prompt this.

Q1: Does this sound reasonable?

Q2: How should I hide the fact these are dates so it's not easily identified and changed?

Many thanks
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft.Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.aspx) namespace is what you need. You will want to look at the two following classes:  [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx)  and  [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx).

You could store the hash code of your  date within the registry key you will use.

Except that I would neither place it in the registry. The AppData folder is a better place, in addition to your local installation folder. Perhaps will you want to to use binaries with the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace so that you can write binary data. The [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) classes are probably what you will need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the hidden common application data directory instead of the registry.  And write the dates in binary format:

```
static string appDataFile;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
   appDataPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, "MyApplication");
   if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(appDataPath))
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataPath);
   appDataFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataPath, "History.dat");

   DateTime[] dates;
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(appDataFile))
      dates = ReadDates();
   else
      dates = new DateTime[] {DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now};

   Console.WriteLine("First: {0}\r\nLast: {1}", dates[0], dates[1]);

   dates[1] = DateTime.Now;
   WriteDates(dates);
}

static DateTime[] ReadDates()
{
   System.IO.FileStream appData = new System.IO.FileStream(
      appDataFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

   List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
   using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(appData))
   {
      while (br.PeekChar() > 0)
      {
         result.Add(new DateTime(br.ReadInt64()));
      }
      br.Close();
   }
   return result.ToArray();
}

static void WriteDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
   System.IO.FileStream appData = new System.IO.FileStream(
      appDataFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);

   List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
   using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(appData))
   {
      foreach(DateTime date in dates)
         bw.Write(date.Ticks);
      bw.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would not store this in the registry because it's really easy to change (at least in the places you can write). I would write it in the Local Data folder in a little file and encrypt it. Probably store it in a couple of places in case someone deletes the file.